# What does it mean when a monster is an "eater of vegetables"?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just came across a unique Risen named Larson the Strange, that was denoted an "eater of vegetables" (where most uniques would have something that makes sense and/or is useful such as "knockback" or "teleporter").

Does this unique actually have a special ability (other than being a tad more resilient like most uniques), or is this merely some sort of joke?

Comment: LOL I didn't saw him while playing beta (or didn't notice) but now i'm quite curious too =)

Comment: Most likely an inside joke like this one from Diablo 1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_U3pU0ehgE

Comment: I guess it means it won't bite your head off after killing you like the other monsters would, as it's vegetarian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Larson is a ["unique"](http://www.diablowiki.com/Unique_Monsters)**, or a specific, named version of a regular monster. Unless quest-required, uniques' titles are apropos of nothing (Easter egg additions). Uniques sometimes have special abilities (like [rare monsters](http://www.diablowiki.com/Rare_Monsters)), but [Larson](http://www.diablowiki.com/Larson_the_Strange) doesn't. **There are no other "eaters of vegetables"**, but maybe that's because none spawn so close to a delicious garden:

As for the joke bit, it may be a connection back to the ["eat your vegetables" subliminal message](http://www.eeggs.com/items/98.html) in *Diablo 1*.<sup>[5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3941317268)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

It is just another Easter egg all blizzard games are full of things like this,especially diablo 3 as it would appear :)

[Here](http://www.diablowiki.com/Digger_O%27Dell) is another monster with weird "ability"

Many of this easter eggs reference to someone or something but no one found anything about Larson yet.