# What do the different colors of enemies' names mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the land of *Diablo III*, enemies come in a few different colors.  Normal, weak mobs are white, then there are those of color: I've seen blue, purple, and yellow.  What do the different colors mean?  Are there other colors?

Answer (score 29):

A **Blue** colored monster is a champion. They come in packs and are guaranteed an item drop. Unlike their Diablo 2 counterparts they have no variants (e.g. posessed, ghostly, etc). They may have special attributes (such as extra fast, extra strong, lightning enhanced).

A **Gold** colored monster is a unique. It is a random spawning, randomly named monster with special attributes, usually accompanied by minions who share its attributes.

A **Purple** colored monster is super unique or a boss. These monsters have preset names and spawn in predictable locations. They have preset attributes which may or may not be shown under their health bar. They can be fully scripted and have unique models as well. Their item drops are usually tied to whether or not you have defeated the monster in the past.

Comment: The blue ones usually come with a "Title" kind like Teleporter, and they can teleport. Take a look [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63698/what-does-it-mean-when-a-monster-is-an-eater-of-vegetables) with information about those "titles".

Comment: Yah, I'm pretty sure blue monsters do have special attributes, we just only saw one of them during the beta.

Comment: It might be a special case but I'll update my answer. I recall an interview at Blizzard were they announced a gauntlet of colors and special types of monsters. So this answer is only based on the beta.

Comment: What about white?

Comment: @ahsteele White was covered in the question.

Comment: @Resorath that's what I get for skimming the question. ;)

Comment: I saw blue creatures with Nightmare last night making me flee.

Comment: @James they probably had the "Nightmarish" attribute

Comment: Lag is the name of a purple boss that spawns everywhere. It doesn't need a loot table because you will never defeat it.

Answer (score 2):

Monsters with a white name are you run-of-the-mill monsters, the ones that are easy to kill.

Monsters with a blue name are champions. They normally come in a group of 3 or 4 and are a little tougher than those white monsters.

Monsters with a yellow name are Unique monsters, that come with their own minions who are tougher than the normal brand of minion.