# Regarding Blinding Flash skill, which enemies are considered "elite"?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Binding Flash's monk skill and runes could affect elite enemies in a different way. But which enemies are considered "elite"? All those [colored](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63740/what-do-the-different-colors-of-enemies-names-mean)? Bosses and mini-bosses are also part of this group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have found, the best formal definition of this actually comes from your achievement log. If you look, there are achievements for killing X number of Elite monsters (either in coop or solo), and it defines them like this:

> Elite Kills (5) – Kill 5 elite monsters (champions, rares or uniques).

As mentioned in the question you linked, champions are the blue-highlighted/named mobs, who come in packs and all have the same abilties. Rares are the yellow-highlighted/named mobs, who have non-rare mobs nearby with the "Minion" attribute (and may have some of the abilities that the champion has). Uniques are the purple-highlighted/named mobs, who will always appear in certain locations.

While bosses are not *highlighted* purple, their names are purple - they do fall into the category of uniques.

Comment: Some type of monsters are immune to blind/fear/confusion but the answer seems correct.