# What is the difference between blue and yellow shining enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the different colors of enemies' names mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63740/what-do-the-different-colors-of-enemies-names-mean)

When you are finished with Diablo 3 on Nightmare, blue and yellow enhanced enemies are common...

But what exactly decides if an enemy shines in yellow or blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blue enemies are [Champions](http://www.diablowiki.net/Champion), which are stronger versions of normal monsters with special properties and buffs. They often appear in small packs.

Yellow enemies are known as "Rare" monsters -- randomly-generated strong monsters with special names, and accompanied by a handful of white "minion" monsters of the same type. If the Rare monster has buffs, its Minions will share those buffs as well.

Aside from being stronger, Champion/Rare monsters will usually drop above-average loot.

Comment: Diablo 3 actually refers to the Yellow monsters as Elites.